# Should I use @HostListener in all directive?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular and I have to listen the scroll event in multiple directives, it's ok to use `@HostListener` in each directive to listen this event or there is a better way to do it?

I don't know if it the same to share a `fromEvent` using `InjectionToken`?

Comment: You should probably specify a little bit what you want to accomplish and the nature of your problem: are you having performance issues? Is everything working but you are wondering if there is a better way? I would say that if what you have is good enough, than you're all right. But we cannot know if it's all right without an explanation.

Comment: multiple event listeners it totally ok